# Can't scroll through page with Orbit Controls

Tags: three.js

I have a threejs scene being rendered in a chunk of content in a website. The page it's on is pretty tall and the user needs to be able to scroll up and down it. This was possible until I implemented the OrbitControls. Now, no matter where my mouse is, scrolling only zooms the camera in and out, and does not scroll the page.

Is it possible for the user to be able to zoom in and out *only* when their mouse is over the canvas, otherwise scroll up and down the page?

Comment: Try `var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);`

Comment: @prisoner849 That's exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: Check out this. Set it to false to let user scroll through the canvas in 100% width of mobile view -> https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.enabled

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having a similar issue, i've disabled zoom by setting .enableZoom to false:

```
const orbit = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
orbit.enableZoom = false;
```

This gives back the scroll functionality to the html, instead of catching it threejs

Read more [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.enableZoom)